# Sonar error message about Repeatable class not found when using Spring's @Scheduled with JDK7

Tags: java, spring, maven, sonarqube, java-7

We are using [Spring's @Scheduled annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) and we use JDK 7. The code is working great, but when we analyse it using Sonar, we get the messages:

```
[DEBUG] Completing symbol : Scheduled
[ERROR] Class not found: java.lang.annotation.Repeatable
```

Is there any way to get rid of this error message?

I tried using [@Schedules annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Schedules.html) to wrap the @Scheduled annotation, as [suggested here](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2013/11/how-to-propertysource-annotations-in.html), but that didn't help. Sonar keeps issuing this message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is triggered when a .class file is not found in the binary dependencies you provide to the analyzer. This message is rather harmless in most cases but might be an indication in some cases that you are lacking some dependencies that can lead to less precise results for some rules (resulting in false negatives).

This ticket changed the level of this log from error to warn in the 3.11 version of the java plugin : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1519

Comment: Thanks. I would love to upgrade our Java plugin, but https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/sonar-maven-plugin/ only contains versions up to 3.0.1. How can I use a later version?

Comment: This is because groupId have changed when codehaus shutdown : https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/java/sonar-java-plugin/ if you can, it is far easier to rely on SonarQube update center feature.

Comment: Thanks, I just also found out that I need to change our groupId. Can you explain how to "rely on SonarQube update center feature"?

Comment: I now realize that my problem is with the maven plugin. It seems the latest version of the sonar maven plugin for maven3 is 3.0.1, and it is this plugin that issues the error. Is there any way to cause the plugin to issue that error as warning? (I don't see how the Update Center on the Sonar server can help here)

Comment: I umarked it as answer, as it doesn't really help. We still get the error from the Maven plugin.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the maven plugin. This message is logged by the sonar-java-plugin : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-frontend/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/resolve/BytecodeCompleter.java#L175 The maven plugin is just a way to call the analyzer, use sonar runner you'll get the same kind of messages, which, as I precised in my answer are not really errors per say.

Comment: But we are using maven. Is there a way to control what sonar-java-plugin the sonar maven plugin uses, so we won't get these errors?

Comment: The maven plugin will use the sonar java plugin on your configured sonarqube server. It will reach out to the server and use what's on it.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot for your close support. I now run into another problem. I can see (https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA/fixforversion/12903/) that 3.11 was released on 26/Feb/16, but the Update Center in our SonarQube server suggest to upgrade to 3.10, and http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin also shows 3.10 as the current version. Can you tell when 3.11 will be available to our Update Center?

Comment: Please open another question or reach out sonarqube@googlegeoups.com (in fact this question has already been answered there)